Terraform error: VM has reported a failure when processing extension
I am trying to run the Ansible conf Powershell file from GitHub on an Azure VM using Terraform, but I get the below error.
Error message:

Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'configansible' (publisher 'Microsoft.Compute' and type
'CustomScriptExtension'). Error message: 'Finished executing command'. More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot. "

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "configansible" {
  name                 = "configansible"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.onboarding.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
      {
        "fileUris": [
          "https://github.com/ansible/ansible-documentation/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
        ],
             "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted -file ./ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
      }
      SETTINGS
}


This error could be because the script failed to download, or PowerShell exited with an error code (non 0). Check in the path C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\ on the deployed VM to see if the script is there. If it is, run it in an elevated PS shell. If it isn't, diagnose Internet connectivity of the VM.

Thanks! I see the ps1 file in the folder, however it seems that it does not actually run.
I have tested it with another script, that simply shows a "Hello World!" pop-up, but it only works if I run the script in the folder manually.

please check whether the VM in question already has a script extension applied. You can do this from the Portal. If so, remove it and try again.

The error message indicating that the issue might be related to the PowerShell script  or the way it is being executed.
To troubleshoot the issue, you can try the below steps.

Check if the PowerShell script is accessible to the VM from GitHub.
Check if the PowerShell script is being executed correctly on local VM.
Check the script if already executed as suggested by Architect Jamie

Here is the script to create a folder with a text file from the storage account using VM extensions deployed with Terraform
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
      name                = "sample-vm"
      resource_group_name = "Venkat"
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "configansible" {
      name                 = "configansible"
      virtual_machine_id   = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
      publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
      type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
      type_handler_version = "1.9"
    
      settings = <<SETTINGS
          {
            "fileUris": [
              "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/script/powershell.ps1"
            ],
                 "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted -file ./powershell.ps1"
          }
          SETTINGS
    }

VM Extension:

After running the script VM extension has been installed on VM.

PowerShell script executed on VM successfully.

